# Issues with Seaborn line graphs going "back left"

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I feel quite dumb but it seems like I can't make my line graph work properly with seaborn. Seems to be related to x Axis but I don't get it.

My source data is raw files from https://www.insee.fr/fr/statistiques/2540004 .
ch3 looks like this just before seaborn:

```
    annais dpt  nombre
18    1952  23       3
23    1956  23       3
29    1961  23       4
31    1962  23       4
33    1963  23       8
35    1964  23      12
37    1965  23      16
39    1966  23      26
41    1967  23      37
43    1968  23      35
47    1969  23      58
51    1970  23      64
55    1971  23      39
59    1972  23      42
63    1973  23      48
67    1974  23      32
71    1975  23      27
75    1976  23      21
79    1977  23      17
83    1978  23      23
87    1979  23      15
91    1980  23      18
95    1981  23      14
99    1982  23       9
103   1983  23       8
107   1984  23      11
111   1985  23       3
115   1986  23       7
119   1987  23       5
129   1990  23       4
..     ...  ..     ...
98    1981  93     208
102   1982  93     209
106   1983  93     162
110   1984  93     180
114   1985  93     136
118   1986  93     126
122   1987  93     112
125   1988  93     100
128   1989  93      64
132   1990  93      61
135   1991  93      71
138   1992  93      56
141   1993  93      40
144   1994  93      54
147   1995  93      42
150   1996  93      30
153   1997  93      17
156   1998  93      21
159   1999  93      14
162   2000  93      17
165   2001  93      28
168   2002  93      16
171   2003  93      10
174   2004  93      11
177   2005  93       4
180   2006  93       4
184   2008  93       5
187   2009  93       4
191   2011  93       4
198   2017  93       4

[199 rows x 3 columns]
```

Basically trying to plot frequency of first names (y axis) by year (x axis) for 4 dept.
Years ('annais') are a four digit integer. I sorted values just to be safe.
Yet the line graph keeps breaking, the values can't stay continuously right to left.
Pandas plot() required a an ad hoc pivot but at least it works.
Any idea ?

Code that works (Pandas plot() ):

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
%matplotlib inline
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [12, 8]

import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv('dpt2017.txt', sep = '\t')
##df = pd.read_csv('nat2017.txt', sep = '\t')
ch = df.loc[df['preusuel'].isin(['CHRISTOPHE'])]
ch = ch[ch.annais != 'XXXX']
ch.nombre.astype(int)
ch.annais.astype(int)
ch = ch.drop(columns=['sexe'])
ch = ch[ch.dpt.isin(['75', '92', '93', '23'])]

ch2=ch.groupby(['preusuel', 'annais', 'dpt']).sum()
ch3=ch2.reset_index()
ch3 = ch3.sort_values(by=['dpt','annais']).drop(columns=['preusuel'])

graph = ch3.pivot(index='annais', columns='dpt', values='nombre')
graph.plot()
```

Result:
[image]

Code that breaks (Seaborn):

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
%matplotlib inline
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [12, 8]

import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

sns.set(style="darkgrid")
df = pd.read_csv('dpt2017.txt', sep = '\t')
##df = pd.read_csv('nat2017.txt', sep = '\t')
ch = df.loc[df['preusuel'].isin(['CHRISTOPHE'])]
ch = ch[ch.annais != 'XXXX']
ch.nombre.astype(int)
ch.annais.astype(int)
ch.annais.astype(int)
ch = ch.drop(columns=['sexe'])
ch = ch[ch.dpt.isin(['75', '92', '93', '23'])]

ch2=ch.groupby(['preusuel', 'annais', 'dpt']).sum()
ch3=ch2.reset_index()
ch3 = ch3.sort_values(by=['dpt','annais']).drop(columns=['preusuel'])

palette = sns.color_palette('muted',4)
ax = sns.lineplot(x="annais", y="nombre", hue = "dpt",palette=palette, data=ch3)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(10))
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(10))
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Is there a way to make this reproducible? See [mcve].

Comment: What's the dtype of `annais`?  You can check this by using `ch3.annais.dtype`

Comment: Actually while checking for a way to make a minimal example, I did found the issue. annais was indeed a str and not a int as it was supposed be because my attemps to cast them was incorrect
`ch['annais']=ch.annais.astype(int)`
and not `ch.annais.astype(int)`

To be honnest I am still not sure about why years as string in alpabetical order don't work but now it's fine.

Thanks a lot to you both !

Comment: tobsecret or ImportanceOfBeingErnest I'd happily give credit for your effort if you post the answer as an answer. I can't accept mine anyway to mark as closed.

Comment: You may accept your own answer in 2 days time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this does not explain why seaborn had a concern with the year 'annais' field being a str, casting it to int worked.
I was trying to do it previously but you have to use `ch['annais']=ch.annais.astype(int)` and not `ch.annais.astype(int)` when you do it !

Thanks a lot @tobsecret and @ImportanceOfBeingErnest